# Slideshow background images in Background

Tags: theming

I'm building a site in Drupal 7. Using the JCarousel module I'm trying to create something similar to this:

http://dale.no/

It's simple enough to create a full width slideshow and adding text over images is not too bothersome with a few adjustments to CSS.

But is it possible to make the images into backgrond CSS images, the same as on the dale.no site? The reason is, when you resize the browser, or use a different size monitor, I would like the centre of the image to remain in the centre of the browser. At the moment, on a square monitor, the centre of the images are cropped by the right hand side of the view port.

Is this possible with this module? Are there are other modules that can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

There are few jquery library which are not using images directly. They are using images as css background.

I found one link for you - http://demo.marcofolio.net/bgimg_slideshow/

The following tutorial might be useful for you- 
http://www.techerator.com/2010/11/how-to-make-a-css-background-slideshow-with-jquery/

This tutorial explains how to use css background images for slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually working on a [Supersized.js](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html) module.   It is not quite ready for production but I can send you a dev version if you want to test it out in it's current stage/provide feedback.

I think this will provide all of the functionality you are after. It is an addon module to the views jqfx module.

Comment: Hi Chance, just wondering if is there any chance you send me supersized module.

Comment: I actuall just posted it to a sandbox on Drupal. http://drupal.org/sandbox/thechanceg/1358600 . Please add any bugs/issues to the issue queue.

Answer (score 0):

Open source contributed Drupal 7 theme is available for this purpose. Photo theme.
https://drupal.org/project/photo

From the theme's project page:

> Photo is a photography and multimedia theme with a full screen slideshow. Showcase your important work, imagination with full screen photo slider. Photo is Drupal theme for photographic professionals, photo artist, amateur photographers to create photo gallery, portfolio with photos, video blogs. It is also useful for architecture, travel sites, hotels, restaurants, sculpture artist and for any purpose who want to emphasis on photos for the website.

Comment: Hello. Could you expand your answer a bit? Is it doing it via CSS, how does it handle image positioning, things that concerned OP?